# How do I generate sitemap for dynamic links in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express, sitemap

I have a jobpage which has url as `/jobpage/:categoryname/:companyname/:jobtitle/:jobid`. Parameters are generated dynamically. I want all such dynamically generated links on sitemap. I have used `express-sitemap` package, code is as below -

```
var sitemap = require('express-sitemap'); 
sitemap({
  sitemap: 'sitemap.xml', // path for .XMLtoFile
  robots: 'robots.txt', // path for .TXTtoFile
  generate: app, // option or function, is the same
  sitemapSubmission: '/sitemap.xml', // path of sitemap into robots
  url : 'xxxx',
  map: {
        '/jobpage': ['get'],
        '/college': ['get'],
               },
  route: { // specific option for some route
    '/jobpage': {
      lastmod: '2016-04-25',
      changefreq: 'weekly',
      priority: 1.0,
    },

  },
}).toFile(); // write sitemap.xml and robots.txt
```

Sitemap is getting generated with link as

```
<url>
<loc>xxxx/jobpage/:categoryname/:companyname/:jobtitle/:jobid</loc>
</url>
```

How do I generate dynamic links? Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Comment: in my case i did it like below.

Create a separate file that sitemap_generator.js which actually read all database models which leads to pages. then generate xml and write to web folder and in interval it keep updating xml as well.

it start creating sitemap when node server start. i did this manually because i found no automated solution comes with limitations.

Comment: Thanks @dev.mraj for your suggestion. Used similar type of logic.

Answer (score 1):

in my case i did it like below.

Create a separate file that sitemap_generator.js which actually read all database models which leads to pages.
then generate xml and write to web folder and in certain interval it keep updating xml as well.

it start creating sitemap when node server start. i did this manually because i found no automated solution comes with limitations.

i think most of time your business logic might not fit into any lib, because that libs can't know what dynamic pages can be. which you already knew.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sitemap